# Language for non-Unicode programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, language

How do I set the language for non-Unicode programs in the current Windows 10? It used to be [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3FlT.png) but the control panel now has different contents.

Comment: This option is still in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Time & Language -> Region -> [on the right] Additional date, time & regional settings -> Region -> Administrative -> Change system locale